# Java Basic Object Oriented Gratuity Calculator

Tags: java

I'm beginning to learn more about Java and I'm trying to code a Gratuity calculator that takes user Input, and shows how much a tip would be at %10 and %20 of the total. I'm getting a single "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error that I can't resolve.

Gratuity class:

```
public class Gratuity{ 

//variables
private double total = 0;   
private double grat1 = 0;
private double grat2 = 0;

public Gratuity(float value){
    total = value;
}

start getters and setters
public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}   

//method to do the calculations
public void calcGrat(){
    grat1 = total * .10;
    grat2 = total * .20;
}
    public double getGrat1(){
    return grat1;
}                   
}
```

And the class with the main method:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; //import package to use the scanner input function


//TestGrat main class contains method
public class TestGrat { 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //method to prompt user for total, double is total
    public void askForInput(){

    try{
        System.out.println("Enter the total amount of your bill");
         total = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.err.printf("Error, please try again. Program will now close");
        System.exit(0);
}       

    }
    public Scanner getKeyboard() {
        return keyboard;
    }
    public void setKeyboard(Scanner keyboard) {
        this.keyboard = keyboard;
    }


//main method
public static void main(String[] args){

// asks for input in float form     

float value = askForInput();

//Creating the gratCalc object and storing value as a float (total)     
Gratuity gratCalc = new Gratuity(value);

// get the total value and set as float
float tot = (float)gratCalc.getTotal();

// converting the float value into string   
System.out.println("You have entered: " + Float.toString(tot));
gratCalc.calcGrat(); //sets grat

// Displaying the options to user 
System.out.println("Below are the tips for %10 as well as %20 ");


//getting the value and then displaying to user with toString       
float getNum = (float) gratCalc.getGrat1();
float getNum1 = (float) gratCalc.getGrat2();

// using the value of getNum as float to put into toString
System.out.println( "For %10: " + Float.toString(getNum));
System.out.println(" For %20: " + Float.toString(getNum1));
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What line is the error in? That would help a lot.

Comment: My original error was on line 36 float value = askForInput();  After implementing some of the replys, there is a new error on line 15 (cannot be resolved into variable)

Answer (score 1):

`askForInput()` is inside your class TestGrat.  However, in `main()` you are calling it directly, as if it was static.  You probably meant:

```
TestGrat test = new TestGrat();
float value = test.askForInput();
```

`askForInput()` is also returning void, so you probably want to fix that too.

Comment: Thank you! It still doesn't see line 15 as a variable, but this fixed my original error.